# HTTP request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, .htaccess, http, https

I am facing problem to call web service which is hosted over HTTP and I am calling web service from https domain.

### web service's htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

i got following error in console when i am trying to calling web.

```
angular.min.js:93 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.<my-domain.com>/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://<api url goes here>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

### Note

Web service is hosted in aws server which is http only. and my website is hosted to other hosting provider.

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, you may wanna try webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok thanks for this

Comment: Just for another question I want to leave my answer for another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65358511/104085

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't fetch insecure (http) resources from a secure (https) origin.

It's called mixed-content and browsers block it for security reasons. (it may allow passive content like images, often with warnings)

What you can do:

- explain to the web service the advantages of https
- proxy the answer of the web service 
  through your sever

Comment: I made other php file where have curl code and that is calling my aws web services and my angular JS call newly created php file.

Comment: @PareshGami As my solution works for you, could you validate my answer? Keep in mind that the connection between your server and the web service is insecure. So it can't be trusted. If you succeed to convince them to switch to https, it will be more secure for everybody !